# Django Save method needs to update model instance twice

Tags: python, django, model

Django Save method needs to update model instance twice for it to work.

An application has the following save method to generate unique ids based on the ID.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    if self.id and not self.fid:
        self.fid = encode(self.id)
```

In reality it only works if model instance is saved twice, the first FID is None.

Comment: Where's the rest of the model? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # save the instance, do this first so that we have an id
    super(MyModelClass, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    # if it was a new instance fid is not set yet
    if self.id and not self.fid:
        self.fid = encode(self.id)
        # save the instance again now that we've set fid
        super(MyModelClass, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: there was Super() at bottom, moving it to above seems have fixed it

Comment: where did you move the second `super` call to?

Comment: Just in case the second save has side effects due to being further overridden, you could replace the code after the `if` statement with: `MyModelClass.objects.filter(id=self.id).update(fid=encode(self.id))`. It's a little weird looking, but it bypasses the `save()`.

Comment: @Anentropic can you please help with a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55384218/how-to-bookmark-a-page-in-django